# How do I use the stripe limit line_items parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, backend

The stripe checkout session object returns the line_items property however by default it only returns the first 10 items, it's possible however to change the number of items it returns with the "limit" parameter which is set to 10 by default. I want to increase this in order to get the full list of items in the order.

The stripe documentation says that in order to change the limit parameter I should use this code:

```
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_51MxoPIFSanYew053tsoTBYgJROU2nApT4UqIsAymFVmoJqBC4oIJ2elZbbfXFcR7Q8mJoMtnrTAfN4YViy8EbdUU00oo4sGJrq');
stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(
  'cs_test_a1Y3FDaVaGm5wKCDDDfFermUlrTAiH3r7BE35KHn3afi7rKjdi9RS7vfaB',
  { limit: 5 },
  function(err, lineItems) {
    // asynchronously called
  }
);
```

However no matter what I do I can't get it to work, I have also input the checkout session id where "cs_test_a1y" etc.. is and still no success.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Since you set limit to 5 which is less than 10, then the response will return 5 items. If you wish to have more items, you should set to higher value. The limit [range](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/line_items?lang=node#retrieve_checkout_session_line_items-limit) is from 1 to 100.